# Laravel Livewire v3 slot troubles

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm using Laravel Livewire v3 and am fairly new to it. I've got a component called `PageHeader`. I'd like to conditionally render additional actions such as buttons on each page, I've tried making a slot, and putting content in it, but don't see it outputting in the slot, what am I missing, here's my component:

```html
<div class="lg:flex lg:items-center lg:justify-between mb-3">
  <div class="min-w-0 flex-1">
    <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold leading-7 text-gray-900 sm:truncate sm:text-3xl sm:tracking-tight">{{ $title ?? '' }}</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="mt-5 flex lg:mt-0 lg:ml-4">
    <x-slot name="actions"></x-slot>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, the usage in my page...

```html
<livewire:page-header title="foo">
    <x-slot name="actions">
      Campaigns
    </x-slot>
  </livewire:page-header>
```